# Creating a unique id in a python dataclass

Tags: python, attributes, attr

I need a unique (unsigned int) id for my python data class. This is *very similar* to [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101476/how-to-create-a-unique-and-incremental-id-in-a-python-class), but *without* explicit ctors.

```
import attr
from attrs import field
from itertools import count
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Person:
    #: each Person has a unique id
    _counter: count[int] = field(init=False, default=count())
    _unique_id: int = field(init=False)

    @_unique_id.default
    def _initialize_unique_id(self) -> int:
        return next(self._counter)
```

Is there any more-"pythonic" solution?

Comment: Just how "unique" should "unique" be? Have you researched the `uuid` module?

Comment: as far as counters go, I think `itertools.count()` is perfect for me, but the whole mechanism of defining the equivalent of a static cpp data member - I wanted to know if there is any other way of doing it

Comment: Is a static variable that's incremented in the constructor a bad idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Use a *default factory* instead of just a *default*.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#default-factory-functions) This allows to define a call to get the next id on each instantiation.
A simple means to get a callable that counts up is to use `count().__next__`, the equivalent of calling `next(...)` on a `count` instance.<sup>1</sup>

The common "no explicit ctor" libraries `attr` and `dataclasses` both support this:

```py
from itertools import count
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class C:
    identifier: int = field(default_factory=count().__next__)

import attr

@attr.s
class C:
    identifier: int = attr.field(factory=count().__next__)
```

To always use the automatically generated value and prevent passing one in as a parameter, use `init=False`.

```
@dataclass
class C:
    identifier: int = field(default_factory=count().__next__, init=False)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If one wants to avoid explicitly addressing magic methods, one can use a closure over a `count`. For example, `factory=lambda counter=count(): next(counter)`.