# Creating a unique id in typescript class

Tags: typescript, global-variables

- I can assign a *unique* index to a python class data member like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195208/creating-a-unique-id-in-a-python-dataclass).
- Is there an equivalent in typescript?

```js
class Person
{
    index: number
    age: number
    name: string

    constructor(age: number, name: string)
    {
        // this.index = fresh index every time 
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a static property or using a randomly generated unique index? If you think that it might help, I write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you figured out, there is no built-in mechanism for auto-incrementing class instance index feature.

As the previous answers and comment suggest, a possible solution, common in OOP, is to use a `static` counter, and incrementing it in the class `constructor`.

JavaScript/TypeScript being not necessarily OOP, like Python, another typical solution is also to use a *closure* (instead of the `static` counter):

```
let counter = 0; // In closure of Person class

class Person {
    index: number
    age: number
    name: string

    constructor(age: number, name: string) {
        this.index = counter++;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person(55, "moish");
var p2 = new Person(74, "uzi");
console.log(p1); // index 0
console.log(p2); // index 1
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAxg9grgOzCAThAvBADAbggenwgEkFpgYBnOFECGAMwgAVVKYypgBDSygKH5delFmw4QA3vwiyIASwQATEAA8AXBARwAtgCNUMudwDmITdv2G5W7jvMRKYFIpOCbsBE5RwoYGCgAFKYOlgYoADS29prergCUUkY2smAAFvKUAHSKKqoY0PBIqADUJTjJKemZWSEFIRUpctXZCHZ0mG32jXIAvvz9-ABu3GgADgCMBQggAO5iKOwIgQCsK1EARDowmWkb8RUj4wBM03MLS4EA7AAsm3AAXvL7FZ7soFkUJoGTBwREuTU2CEHHeIE+MG+Y2Of0ICmUQIm-CAA)

---

A common factorization is to separate this auto-incrementing index feature into a base class:

```
let counter = 0; // In closure of WithAutoIncrementedIndex class

class WithAutoIncrementedIndex {
    index: number;

    constructor() {
        this.index = counter++;
    }
}

// All classes that extend WithAutoIncrementedIndex will have
// the auto-incrementing index feature,
// but sharing the same counter
class Person extends WithAutoIncrementedIndex {
    age: number
    name: string

    constructor(age: number, name: string) {
        super(); // Call the parent constructor
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person(55, "moish");
var p2 = new Person(74, "uzi");
console.log(p1); // index 0
console.log(p2); // index 1
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAxg9grgOzCAThAvBADAbggenwgEkFpgYBnOFECGAMwgHUBLMACwEE4wZSotALYgkIACalxIAB7kAhpUoAoZVGCLKLdt178EgkCLGSE0uQG9lEGxFZnZALggI4QgEaocq29BgJKMBQ4KD4UAAoASggrX19OVkoAOntzDD9EZBQAamzvXwBfZSLlQgguYGAFJRAtTnlIWWQzbU4ePgFhUWRTNIB3VkqIDnkANxBSok46eT0AWntDYzB7AHM7BzkGEAaaEAAaSYh3XghKEZQ1iGmz+REMsRQ1DSUIAAVUSn8IJtFxLTYbT0nSM3QkUlkMWstnkqxAzlcHlQ0JsCDu8LOQTWPlssACQRCYXCsIxiM8KH2LnRzkClwQq2isTiNmoAAdUFE8GUAMLyIY3VnyWhIPz44KhGBPZk2BLJEnpEn5aWypJo+6YNUgJU2IolUZCiCsgCM6QQID670+-nCAFYbZSAERCGCJDgOyLefVoVkAJlN5stKC+CHCAHYACyOuAAL1Y7u8eK+oCSFFW4WNHoIRFSkKwan8SZAKZgad9mbKObkRuUQA)

---

BTW, in your constructor, you do not need to explicitly assign your class members if they are already used as constructor parameters with the same name and a visibility modifier, see [Class Parameter Properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties):

> TypeScript offers special syntax for turning a constructor parameter into a class property with the same name and value. These are called *parameter properties* and are created by prefixing a constructor argument with one of the visibility modifiers `public`, `private`, `protected`, or `readonly`.

So you can do directly:

```
class Person extends WithAutoIncrementedIndex {
    constructor(public age: number, public name: string) {
        super(); // Call the parent constructor
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#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-m9IF9MH9ZqDZVDcmlyiAA)

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of [@mahooresorkh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15235482/mahooresorkh), using `static` solves it:

```js
class Person
{
    index: number
    age: number
    name: string

    // arrggghh this is ugly 
    static gIndex: number = 0;
    static getFreshIndex(): number
    {
        Person.gIndex += 1;
        return Person.gIndex; 
    }

    constructor(age: number, name: string)
    {
        this.index = Person.getFreshIndex();
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person(55, "moish");
var p2 = new Person(74, "uzi");
console.log(p1);
console.log(p2);
```

I wonder if there's a simpler way (?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, there's no simplier way that using a static member

```
class Person {
  // 0~1 number
  numberRandomUid = Math.random()
  // 6-char [0-9a-z] string
  stringRandomUid = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 8)
  // non-serializable
  symbolRandomUid = Symbol()

  // ordered int, dunno how will work with inheritance
  static gIndex = 0;
  numberOrdered = Person.gIndex ++;
  // or numberOrdered = ++ Person.gIndex;
  // or numberOrdered = Person.gIndex += 1;


  constructor(
    public age: number, 
    public name: string) { }
}
```